# MsGraph shared mailbox operations

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Are the following operations possible through the MsGraph API.

- Add an user to a shared mailbox
- Create a shared mailbox
- Delete a shared mailbox
- Remove an user from a shared mailbox
- Rename a shared mailbox

From my searches and reading the MsGraph API documentation I could not find any end point for doing the above apart from reading shared mailbox mails.  Is this correct ?  If this is not possible through the MsGraph API should I use the ExchangeAPI ?  I did some reading on the Exchange API and also could not find a proper endpoint to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph currently does not support this. I see this feature request  - [Graph API manage shared mailbox access](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-manage-shared-mailbox-access/idi-p/2432951) that talks about the same thing

I suggest you you upvote it and add comments so that it may be implemented in the future.